# Display images according to number set from interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

i try to display from svg ,layers according to numbers set from an interval.I have 2 random numbers (left and right) set to display from interval (10,99) both.That works good,but, i need to display layer 1(banane1) from svg if left || right belongs to interval (10,20) , then if left || right belongs to interval (20,30) to display layer 2(banane2) from svg and so on untill left || right belongs to interval (90,99) to display layer 9(banane9). There are 9 intervals and 9 layers from svg to display. Code i wrote looks like :

FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/r68Bg/

```
for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        panouri = document.getElementById('panou' + i);
        svgDoc = panouri.contentDocument; 
    }
```

where panou0 and panou1 are 2 svg that has layers 2 numbers where i display later random numbers set from intervals and 9 layers each with different content which must be displayed according to random numbers.

```
function randomIntFromInterval(min,max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)+min);
};

function conditions(){
        left = randomIntFromInterval(10,99);
        right = randomIntFromInterval(10,99);

    for(var i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        ecuations.push(left, right);
        randoms = document.getElementById("panou" + i).contentDocument;
        numere = randoms.getElementById("number");      
        numere.textContent = ecuations[i];
        }    
};
```

where i add into my svg (panou0 and panou1) randoms numbers from set intervals.

```
function setBananeState(state)
{
    for(var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    svgItem = svgDoc.getElementById("banane" + i);
    svgItem.setAttribute("display", "none");  
    svgItem = svgDoc.getElementById(state);
    svgItem.setAttribute("display", "inline");
    }
};

    function getBanane(){
    if(left || right >= 30 && left || right <= 40){
        bananeState = "banane3";
        setBananeState(bananeState); 
    }
};
```

Here i have all layers from svgs which contains bananas to display according to random number given and a function getBanane() which has condition to display layer1 (banane1 by id from svg) if random number is from interval (10,20).Unfortunately this doesnt work...and i must have 8 more condition to display layers from svg if random numbers are from different interval

Comment: Please fix your formatting and typos in your code. You question is already hard to follow without missing a `}` in `getBanane`. If you could put your code in a fiddle it might really help too.

Comment: sure,in a minute im gonna add a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to work:

```
if(left || right == randomIntFromInterval(10,20)){
```

What you are doing here is a `OR`ing `left` with `right` which will give you a boolean which you are then comparing to `randomIntFromInterval`. I think what you are trying to do is this:

```
var interval = randomIntFromInterval(10,20);
if (left == interval || right == interval) {
```

**EDIT**: Okay you changed your question. So now this:

```
if(left || right >= 30 && left || right <= 40){
```

Is not right, you can't write an `if` statement like that in javascript, or in most (probably all) programming languages. You can't say "if a or b is greater than x", like you would in normal English speech because it's ambiguous. You have to explicitly say "if (a is greater than x) or (b is greater than x)". So your `if` statement above needs to become:

```
if ((left >= 30 || right >=30) && (left <= 40 || right <= 40)) {
```

Although I'm not sure this is exactly what you want either. Because here if `left==0` and `right==41`, then this statement would be true. I think you want either left or right to be in the interval, so your best check would be:

```
if ((left >= 30 && left <= 40) || (right >= 30 && right <= 40)) {
```

Comment: Yeap,this look much better,is exactly what i need ...but how to make a condition which include all intervals (10,20) ,(20,30),(30,40)....(90,99)

Comment: Damn...var interval gets random now from the interval set :( I need to check if left or right belongs to this interval (10,20) so if my left or right is 12 to return true , if left or right is 21 to return false